# SQL Date saved as Hex-value how to get it back into a Date-format

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, datetime

Hello fellow stackoverflowers,

I got a little problem.

In a Table I got a column with a date inside it, but it is stored as a Hexvalue.

For example:

```
0xF2F84BF0F44BF2F0F1F6
```

I know that there is a date behind it.

I tried:

I stored the hex value, while running the stored procedure, in a variable called "@date"

```
SELECT Cast(@date as datetime)
```

But this gives me a cryptic version of an "o" back.

When I try to use `Convert(datetime,@date,103)` I get an error that the binary value couldn't get converted into datetime.

I hope someone can help me.

Greetings 
Soul

Comment: If you got it from running through a stored procedure, you can see how the data was converted into HEX. Could you give us that information?

Comment: I use a stored procedure to work with the data, it dosn't get placed in the table via a stored procedure.

Comment: I agree with Allan, you need to find out how that hex value is generated, it isn't a standard format. If you know what date it is supposed to produced, you may be able to reverse engineer it.

Comment: Well - the value of the binary number/hex seems too high for a datetime type, so something else is going on.

Comment: I got it with help with this statment: select * from openquery(server, 'select cast(DATUM as char(10) CCSID 273) as Verfalldatum from db');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution that works, it is the following:

`select * from openquery(connectionserver, 'select cast(Date as char(10) CCSID 273) as wastedate from database');`

Comment: My guess for the German translation would be expirationdate, not wastedate, but this doesn't look like the hex-conversion at all...

Comment: Honestly who cares how it is translated, it is not relevant for the asked question or solution. Well if you dont think it works try it with the hex-value I stated in the Question. The hex-value comes out of a IBM iSeries AS400 and has a size of 10. Behind it is a date.